# Simple way to contour netcdf variables on a map using r package

Tags: r, dictionary, geo, netcdf

I have to draw maps using R package so that country limits are plotted, and also the contours for the values of a meteorological variable read from a NetCDF file.

I do the following:

```
r=raster('netcdffile.nc')
map('worldHires', xlim=c(-10,50), ylim =c(30,50))
plot(r, add = TRUE)
contour(r, add = TRUE)
```

but the country limits don't appear.
It seems that the plotting of the raster, eliminates the country limits previously drawn.
I need a simple wway, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attaching an example netcdf file with correct coordinates would help. I don't have any netCDF file here on hand to test. Did you try the excellent `rasterVis` package? You can easily plot using trellis or ggplot, and add the map in the usual ways.

For example with `rasterVis` and `ggplot2` something like this should work:

```
r=raster('netcdffile.nc')
library(rasterVis)
library(maps)
world <- data.frame(map(plot=FALSE)[c("x","y")])
gplot(r) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill=value)) + 
  geom_path(data=world, aes(x,y)) +  
  stat_contour(aes(z=value)) +
  coord_equal()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Your code seems to work when I copy and paste it on the console, but not when run as a script as `source("script.R")`. Also, I need to use the function `locator` and `identify`, and these seem not to work in the generated graphic.

Comment: @AntonioSerrano This has been covered before many times. When sourcing scripts, you need a print() statement to enclose the plotting command (http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f). For using `locator` and `identify` ggplot isn't the best option. You can use `gglocator` from the `ggmap` package. The other option is to use lattice or base graphics and use the standard tools provided. The `rasterVis` manual is a very good read about this.